# Handshaked failed when call to AppEngine from Android App

Tags: android, api, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I am the newbie in App Engine so I have some confusion about it.
When I deploy my service to App Engine it default has SSL because I see the API link has https **"https://abcdefgh.r.appspot.com/"**. I didn't config anything on SSL of App Engine.

When I build the Android App call to that API some devices can but some others can not, my customer can not but my phone can, so I can't reproduce the problem, and the error is ***java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException***

Please help me how can I solve it or any way to check it? why it just happened on some devices?
Do I need to config SSL on App Engine or Android App?

On Android, I am using the Coroutine and OkHttp to make request.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

What version of OkHttp are you using? There is already an answer here [1] using OkHttp3

Are you using self-signed certificates? Self-signed certs are not trusted from Android.

The error (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException) can also be caused when the Certificate Authority (CA) is unknown. A detailed description of this error is given here [2]

Regarding creating SSL certificates with App Engine (for custom Domains), you can either use Google Managed or Self Managed (custom) certificates [3]

Hope I could help!

[1] [Use a certificate in an okhttp request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637121/use-a-certificate-in-an-okhttp-request-with-android)

[2] https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl