# mTLS X509 authenticated request in Java

Tags: java, authentication, x509certificate, x509, mtls

I'm looking for a way to implement the following mTLS authenticated request in Java:

```
PFX=x509.pfx

curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/' \
  --cert-type p12 \
  --cert "$PFX:mySecretPassword"
```

I'm using a x509 pfx file encrypted with a password.

Answer (score 0):

For server side, choose framework like Spring.
Check Spring Security docs for more.
Here is intro https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

To implement client only try okHttp,
that is usually troublesome to use custom certificate in client, e.g. [Use a certificate in an okhttp request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637121/use-a-certificate-in-an-okhttp-request-with-android)

So state what exactly you want, and raise better question.

As an advise, try to use standard/default configuration as much as possible.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate